# Issue in Convert time from 12 hours format to 24 hours in Smasung galaxy s6 Edge

Tags: android, date, simpledateformat, date-parsing, samsung-galaxy

Using this method to convert time "02:00 PM" = "14:00" 
This method is working well with Moto g3, Moto g4, Lenovo K3 note, Samsung Galaxy J3 ..please help me out to fix this issue...

```
 public static String convertTimeto24hours(String time) {
    String timein24hours = "";
    try {

        SimpleDateFormat displayFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm");
        SimpleDateFormat parseFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm a");
        Date date = null;
        try{
            date = parseFormat.parse(time);
            System.out.println(parseFormat.format(date) + " = " + displayFormat.format(date));
        }catch (ParseException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        timein24hours = "" + displayFormat.format(date);

        return timein24hours;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        print(e);
        Log.error("convertTimeto24hours",e);
    }
    return timein24hours;
}
```

Comment: You don't describe the concrete error so I can only speculate... Maybe you should set the locale explicitly to the expected language (probably English) because parsing am/pm-strings is locale-dependent. Furthermore, the capitalization or the usage of interpunctuation chars in am/pm-markers might also be a problem which could require some kind of string preprocessing.

Comment: ya s6 displays a.m. / p.m. rather than other stock android phone like am & pm..........May be string is the issue...Thanks for suggestion I will try to detect it and get back to you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need to set the `Locale` . because when you don't set that, system pick up default locale. here is simple code:

```
SimpleDateFormat displayFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm",Locale.US);
SimpleDateFormat parseFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm a",Locale.US);
```

Comment: Perfect Answer !